# Symbol breaking plotly map

Tags: r, plotly, mapbox

I'm trying to create a map of the AirBnb listings in Boston with additional markers such as police stations, bike stations, ramps, parking meters, hospitals, and ev stations. Whenever I try to change the shape of the markers with `symbol`, it breaks the plot.

Here is the code that creates a scatter mapbox for the Boston listings:

```
p <- 
  plot_mapbox(boston_airbnb, width = 1200, height = 900) %>% 
  add_markers(
    x = ~longitude,
    y = ~latitude,
    color = ~log_price,
    name  = "Log (base 10) of price",
    text = 
      ~paste(
        name,
        "\nRoom type:", room_type,
        "\nPrice: ", price,
        "\nNeighborhood", neighbourhood,
        "\nMinimum nights: ", minimum_nights
      ),
    hoverinfo = "text"
  ) %>% 
  layout(
    mapbox = 
      list(
        center = list(lat = 42.32, lon = -71.1),
        zoom = 9.5,
        style = "dark"
      )
  )
```

Here was an attempt at adding hospitals as red squares:

```
p_h <- p %>% 
  add_trace(
    data = hospitals,
    x = ~Longitude,
    y = ~Latitude,
    mode = 'markers',
    name = "Hospitals",
    text = ~paste(Name,
                  "\nAddress: ", Address),
    hoverinfo = "text",
    marker = list(symbol = 'square', color = 'red', size = 10)
  )
```

This attempt correctly places the markers as squares but it the color of the points are white. If I did it without a square symbol, it would correctly output red points. I've tried add_markers(), using I(), customizing the markers outside of a list for marker =, etc.

When I try to add the bike stations to the hospital code, the markers don't even appear. However, they do appear when I remove the shape of the symbol.

```
p_h <- p %>% 
  add_trace(
    data = hospitals,
    x = ~Longitude,
    y = ~Latitude,
    mode = 'markers',
    name = "Hospitals",
    text = ~paste(Name,
                  "\nAddress: ", Address),
    hoverinfo = "text",
    marker = list(symbol = 'square', color = 'red', size = 10)
  ) %>% 
  add_trace(
    data = bikes,
    x = ~Longitude,
    y = ~Latitude,
    mode = 'markers',
    name = "Bike Stations",
    hoverinfo = "text",
    marker = list(symbol = 'triangle-up', color = 'pink', size = 10)
  )

p_h
```

The legend displays everything correctly.

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer the question, but is leaflet an option?  If so, its markers are image files, so you have lots of choice of what icons are placed at the marker values.

Comment: Please post, at a minimum: your OS, your R-version, and your `plotly` library version.

Comment: In addition, please post the mapbox "token" you are using -- along with the info on where to get it (i.e.  https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/ or equivalent )

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My OS is windows, R version 4.2.3, plotly library version 4.10.1

My mapbox token is: pk.eyJ1IjoiYm9zdG9uY29ubm9yMTEiLCJhIjoiY2xncXIya2VxMGc1cTNmc2I3NjFoY2NkMyJ9.fcKb-W66WPlzv4oOx6ZC4A

Not sure if this is what you meant but I created the token by just going to the mapbox website and setting up an account. Please let me know if anything else I could provide would be helpful

Comment: I'm not handing out my credit card info.  Perhaps you can create a *small, reproducible* data set for us to test rather than pulling a file from mapbox.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Not sure where you're being asked for credit card info... I learned about  mapbox via one of my data visualization classes. All we were told to do was to create a mapbox token for free by creating an account which I did. I'm not asking you to pull any file from mapbox. Majority (I think all) of the markers I used with their coordinates were from https://data.boston.gov/group/geospatial. I just used mapbox to render the map for plotly.